# web application to upload the users data such as images

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am creating a webapplication using php, html hosted on LAMP virtual server.
My application main function would be for sellers to put an Advertisement for sale. Later the buyers will view the Advertisement and buy it online.

My question here is while a seller is posting his Ad(which includes images and video). Can I use only mysql to store all the sellers data and later retrieve it through mysql queries and display to buyers. Is this way of building an application is good or any other ways to store data and retrieve is suggested.

I am learning application building please guide me

Comment: As a programmer, you can store however you want. But yes, reading and writing to and from a database such as MySQL is a very common pattern.

Comment: Yes, you can use a database to store data.

Comment: Also, if you are learning to program, don't worry too much about right/wrong, best/better. etc. Security-aside, generally just getting something to actually work, then break, then work again is one of the best ways to learn to program.

Comment: If you are wanting to store big files such as videos, it might be more efficient to store them on disk somewhere, and just put the location of those files (i.e. the filename and path on disk) into MySQL. Although some database engines have got better at file storage and retrieval in recent years, if you have a fast disk you might achieve better performance reading and writing the files from disk than via the database engine, especially for bigger files, and/or if the site is busy.

Comment: Or you could offer sellers a way to embed videos hosted on other sites like youtube, vimeo, etc. That saves you bandwidth and disk space, and the seller can then re-use their video for other purposes too, which they might be happy about. This is quite a common way for sites to provide video functionality nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as data storage is concerned, MySQL seems like a good start for storing non-binary and binary information from a web application. However, When dealing with files and multimedia it is better to store the files in a proper file storage system such as the hard drive.

As you scale in your web application, MySQL would increase the latency in retrieving files, So I suggest you store the images or videos in a folder on your server and then save the filename and its path on MySQL as a string.